# specific query with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need help with specific query. I am using neo4j. My database consists of companies (nodes) and transactions between them(relationship). Each relationship(PAID) has properties:
amount- for amount of transaction
year - year of transaction
month - month of transaction

What I need, is to find all cycles in a graph, starting at node A. It must also be true that transaction occurred one after another.

So valid example would be A PIAD B in march, B PAID C in april, C PAID A in june.

So is there any way to get all cycles from node A, so that transactions occur in continuous order?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set up a sample graph at [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org) to share or at least tell more about what version of Neo4j you are using, but if you're using 2.0 and if you store year and month as long or integer, then maybe you could try something like

```
MATCH a-[ab:PAID]->b-[bc:PAID]->c-[ca:PAID]->a 
WHERE (ab.year + ab.month) > (bc.year + bc.month) > (ca.year + ca.month)
RETURN a,b,c
```

**EDIT:**
Actually that was hasty, the additions won't work that way of course, but the structure should be ok. Maybe

```
WHERE ((ab.year > bc.year) or (ab.year = bc.year AND ab.month > bc.month))
    AND ((bc.year > ca.year) OR (bc.year = ca.year AND bc.month > ca.month))
```

or

```
WHERE (ab.year * 12 + ab.month) > (bc.year * 12 + bc.month) > (ca.year * 12 + ca.month)
```

If you only use dates for this type of comparison, consider storing them as one property, perhaps as milliseconds since 'epoch' 1/1 -70 GMT. That makes comparisons very easy. But if you need to return and display dates frequently, then keeping them separate might make sense.

**EDIT2:**
I can't think of a way to build your condition of "r1.date < r2.date" into the pattern, which means matching all variable depth cycles and then discarding some (most) of them. That's wont to become expensive in a large graph, and you may be better off building a traversal or server plugin, which can make complex iterative decisions during the traversal. In 2.0, thanks to Wes' elegant collection slicing, you could try something like this

```
MATCH path=a-[ab:PAID*..10]->a 
WHERE ALL (ix IN range(0,length(ab)-2) 
    WHERE ((ab[ix]).year * 12 +(ab[ix]).month)<((ab[ix+1]).year * 12 +(ab[ix+1]).month)) 
RETURN path
```

The same could probably be achieved in 1.9 with `HEAD()` and `TAIL()`. Again, share sample data in a console and maybe someone else can pitch in.

Comment: I am using neo4j 1.9. This query is OK, but it is only for cycles that contains three nodes, is there any way to make it universal, so one query returns all cycles, of all sizes, not just size 3?

Comment: You still haven't shared a sample graph or details about your model, or what you have tried so far. If that's too much work you may want to consider paying for support.